# @2x images do not display in XCode4 interface builder designer

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode4

I'm trying to design a xib using XCode4, but when I put down an image view that displays an @2x image xcode doesn't preview it correctly (it displays a missing image icon).
It works correctly when the app is run though.

As an example: I add a UIImageView to my view and set the image property to test.png.
In my project I add a file named test@2x.png.

In XCode 3.2 this image would have correctly displayed in IB, and the @2x version would have automatically half-sized on non-retina devices.

However in IB in XCode4 the image does not display.

Is anyone else experiencing this? If they are, it's a pretty massive issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add both images? AFAIK UIImage isn’t guaranteed to work like that.

Comment: Our workflow is that we use @2x images and then late in development run through the app and add scaled down versions of images where the automatically scaled ones don't look good. 
Having two versions of images during dev is a bit of a pain in the arse, as you have to generate both if you make changes to one. Also we like to use as few images as possible to keep bundle size to a minimum.

Up until XCode4 this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I always use both sizes, having the @2x ones first, and unretining them using the free app unretiner from app store, and drop both sizes to the project. When referring to an image, instead of writing `test.png` or `test@2x.png`, I write `test` and xCode finds sizes to the corresponding devices, but YES! in IB, the image won't be displayed in this way, just a question marked blue screen; but that works fine when running the app.